# Basic Reverse Polish CL Parser

Tags: c, programming-challenge, math-expression-eval

> **K and R Exercise 5-10**
>
> Write the program expr, which evaluates a reverse Polish expression
>   from the command line, where each operator or operand is a separate
>   argument.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> expr 2 3 4 + *
> ```
>
> evaluates
>
> ```
> 2 * (3+4)
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "expression_parser.h"

int parse_polish(int size, char *expression[])
{
    char *entry;
    int temp1, temp2;

    if (expression[1] && ((isdigit(*expression[1]) &&
        isdigit(*expression[2])))) {
        stack_init(&size, expression);
        expression++;
        for ( ; *expression; expression++) {
            if (isdigit(*(entry = *expression)))
                push(atoi(entry));
            else {
                switch (*entry) {
                    case '+':
                        push(pop() + pop());
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        temp1 = pop();
                        temp2 = pop();
                        push(temp1 - temp2);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        push(pop() * pop());
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        temp1 = pop();
                        temp2 = pop();
                        if (!(temp2))
                            return -1;
                        else 
                            push(temp1 / temp2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return pop();
    } else 
          return -1;
}
```

[Repository](https://github.com/aorlandogit/k_and_r/tree/master/src/chapter_5/express)

Comment: So what exactly are you asking, exactly?

Comment: Just a code review.

Answer (score 1):

- Your function is called `parse_polish()`, but it actually does much more: it evaluates the expression too!
- `pop()` takes no arguments, and `push()` takes just one argument, so I deduce that they must be operating on a global variable, which is bad practice.
- Your function returns `-1` on error, but that could very well also be the result of a legitimate calculation.  I recommend one of the following strategies:

  - Passing the calculation result as an out-parameter.
  - Requiring the caller to initialize the stack and pass it to your evaluator.  The caller can then pop the result off the stack (which could be empty in case of an error).
  - Using floating-point calculations.  Not only do you get floating-point division, but you also have the possibility of returning positive infinity, negative infinity, or NaN.
- Why do you test that `*expression[1]` and `*expression[2]` are digits?  What if the expression consists of a single token `{ "5" }` — shouldn't the result be `5`?
- Perhaps you want to allow negative integers as inputs too?

Comment: Thank you @200_success the other files are in the repository linked below the segment! I'll definitely take these thoughts into consideration.